# How can i delete the row correctly? I have the crash when i delete the row in table view i have this thread

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift4

this is the thread : 
 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (19) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (19), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

this is the code delete the row

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableShow: UITableView!

    var person = [NSManagedObject]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")

        do {
            let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            person = results as! [NSManagedObject]

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Fetching Error: \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return person.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)


        let personA = person[indexPath.row]
        let firstName = personA.value(forKey: "firstName")
        let lastName = personA.value(forKey: "lastName")
        let age = personA.value(forKey: "age")
        if age != nil {

            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(firstName!) \(lastName!), age \(age!)"
        }
        else {

            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(firstName!) \(lastName!)"
        }
        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            var all = [[person]]

        all[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath] , with: .fade)

       // tableView.reloadData()
            }

    }

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

        if editing {
            tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
        } else {
            tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: don't call `tableView.deleteRows` inside the delegate function, try to remove  the element from the managed object and after that only call `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Show your `numberOfRowsInSection` code. The code you have shown is telling the tableview that you are deleting a row but it doesn’t update  your actual data store, so you get a crash.  Also, you should either call `deleteRows` (which is preferred) or call `reloadData`.  Calling both is redundant.

Comment: i try but the same problem i want to give the all code and please edit the code

Comment: you are removing the time from the array `all` which you just initialized within the scope of the delegate method. you need to remove from your data source `person` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the element directly from the person variable, and reloading the data.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        person.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: this is deleted without crash 
 but when you swipe the other view controller  thee data removed is retured